# Why do I get the error message when I try to create a one to many relationship?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I use the entity framework core, and try to create a one to many relationship between two tables. I want my User to be able to make many tickets.

Here are my models and this is what my one to many relationship looks like.

**Application User**

```
     [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string RoleId { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string Role { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ProjectUsers> ProjectUsers { get; set; }

        List<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
```

**Tickets**

```
 [Key]
        public int Ticket_Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string TicketName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string TicketDescription { get; set; }

        public DateTime TicketCreated { get; set; }

        public string TicketPriority { get; set; }

        public string TicketType { get; set; }

        public string TicketStatus { get; set; }
       
        List<Comments> Comments { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("Project")]
        public int Project_Id { get; set; }
        public Project Project { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

**Here are my LINQ where the error occures**

```
 public IActionResult Details(int id) 
        {
          
            IEnumerable<Ticket> obj = _db.Tickets
                .Include(p => p.Project)
                .Where(m => m.Project_Id == id);


            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(obj);
         }
```

**My DBcontext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comments> Commenents{ get; set; }


        //Many to Many Project and Users
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectUsers>().HasKey(ba => new { ba.Project_Id, ba.UserId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectUsers>().HasOne(b => b.Project).WithMany(b => b.ProjectUsers).HasForeignKey(b => b.Project_Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectUsers>().HasOne(b => b.ApplicationUser).WithMany(b => b.ProjectUsers).HasForeignKey(b => b.UserId);
        }

    }
```

It has gone well and i have made the relationship. The only problem I have is when I click on a page that receives TicketId then I get this problem `SqlException: Invalid column name 'UserId'.`  .Before I made the relationship, it worked well, but now it seems to have become a problem. I can not understand what it could be?

Another thing I noticed is that when I look in my database, there do not seem to be any keys between tables. However, I have added a migration and updated the database

Comment: Advice: Stick to the standard naming scheme in EF Core. Name primary keys "Id" and foreign keys <class name>Id, e.g. `ApplicationUserId`. Then you can skip some of the annotations.

Comment: I Will think about that in the future, thank you !

Comment: Where in the generated SQL is the invalid column name? And, BTW, what's the (LINQ) query that generates it?

Comment: @GertArnold I have posted my LINQ now :) I Think there are issue with my UserId key.

Comment: Are your ApplicationUser and Tickets classes belong to the same DB Context? If you are using built-in ASP.NET Core Identity the ApplicationUser class is in IdentityContext while your application entity classes such as Tickets belong to Application DbContext and you cannot make relation as you did in your sample.

Comment: How did you get UserId and ApplicationUser  with linq?You only shows how to get `Project`?

Comment: @MajidShahabfar I have posted my dbcontext now. I use built in asp.net core identity. But i have application user in my dbcontext

Comment: @YiyiYou I get an error message when I open the view that belongs to this controller therefore I post it :)

Comment: Study this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0